# std::list< pair<double, int> >::iterator declaration not working

Tags: c++, list, iterator

The problem i am having is declaring an iterator for a list of type
list< pair >
I feel like there is something really obvious happening. Google is not my friend
today.

See the for loop below, assume using namespace std

```
        for (list< pair<double, int> >::iterator i = terms.begin(); i != terms.end(); ++i)
        {
            yval += pow(di, i->second) * i->first;
        }
```

The errors are a huge wall of errors here they are read at will

```
 te<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool
std::operator==(const std::basic_string
    <_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2516:5:
note:   temp
    late argument deduction/substitution failed:
    polynomial.cpp:40:44: note:   'std::list<std::pair<double, int> >::iterator {aka std::_Lis
    t_iterator<std::pair<double, int> >}' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT,
     _Traits, _Alloc>'
    In file included from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/locale_facets
    .h:50:0,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/basic_ios.h:3
    9,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/ios:45,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/ostream:40,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/iostream:40,
                     from polynomial.h:7,
                     from polynomial.cpp:1:
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:206:5:
note: t
    emplate<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_
    CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:206:5:
note:
     template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    polynomial.cpp:40:44: note:   'std::list<std::pair<double, int> >::iterator {aka std::_Lis
    t_iterator<std::pair<double, int> >}' is not derived from 'const std::istreambuf_iterator<
    _CharT, _Traits>'
    In file included from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/mingw32/bits/c++al
    locator.h:34:0,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:4
    8,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/deque:62,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/queue:61,
                     from polynomial.h:5,
                     from polynomial.cpp:1:
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:129:5:
note: templat
    e<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_
    cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:129:5:
note:   templ
    ate argument deduction/substitution failed:
    polynomial.cpp:40:44: note:   'std::list<std::pair<double, int> >::iterator {aka std::_Lis
    t_iterator<std::pair<double, int> >}' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<
    _Tp>'
    In file included from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.
    h:68:0,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/deque:61,
                     from e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/queue:61,
                     from polynomial.h:5,
                     from polynomial.cpp:1:
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:813:5:
note: templat
    e<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_
    iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container
    >&)
    e:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:813:5:
note:   templ
    ate argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `terms`?

Comment: it is a private member of the class with the same pattern
`list< pair<double, int> > terms;`

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/910add0cb3aee71b), please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe `terms` is being shadowed? Have you tried using `auto` instead of explicitly giving the iterator type?

Comment: Does your code is inside const member function?

Comment: if so, use list< pair<double, int> >::const_iterator

Comment: it is not a const member function, I will work on creating a mvce

Comment: I don't think that OP has posted the complete code. The compiler shows that some `std::operator==` is used between the iterator and some `std::string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the mvce solved it for me the error was a function call within the for loop.

`char sign = (i->first <= 0 || i == terms.begin)? '\0' :'+';`

nothing to do with the ::iterator. Appreciate everyone's time and advice.